# Find a necessary and sufficient condition such that the sequence is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let $a>0.$ Define the sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}$ by $$x_{n+1}=a+x_n^2,\,x_0=0.$$
>   Find a necessary and sufficient condition such that the sequence is convergent.
>
> ---

If $x_n\to l,$ then by passing the limit and solving the quadratic equation, we get $l=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1-4a}}{2}.$ So, **necessarily** $a\le 1/4.$
I am not able to obtain the sufficient condition. I know that the sequence is increasing which I proved by induction$(x_{n+1}-x_n=x_n^2-x_{n-1}^2).$ By Monotone convergence theorem if I am able to show that the sequence is bounded, I'm done.

Comment: If any $x_n$ exceeds 1, the sequence diverges.  Does that help?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang it seems the op already knows $a\le 1/4$, in particular $a <1$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang This came to my thoughts, but i realised that still this is only a sufficient condition for divergence of the sequence

Comment: Ah, I was still thinking about sufficiency.  Sorry.   Must apply more coffee.

Comment: By induction you can show that $x_{n+1} \leq 2a$ if $a \leq 1/4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question contains its own answer. $a\leq 1/4$ is the nessessary and sufficient condition.

Indeed, if $a\leq 1/4$, prove by induction that $x_n<1/2$. The base of the induction is trivial. Step of the induction: if $x_n<1/2$, then $x_{n+1}<1/4+(1/2)^2=1/2$.

This proves the boundedness, hence convergence of the sequence $(x_n)$.